# Maven plugin plugin descriptor goal does not generate mojo description documentation when using annotations

Tags: java, xml, maven, maven-plugin, xml-documentation

According to the [Maven Plugin Plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html), when creating a Mojo, you are supposed to use an `@Mojo(...)` annotation to denote that your class is a Mojo. Then, when you run the `plugin:descriptor` goal, you *should* have various XML files created with details about your Mojo such as [this one](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-plugin-api/plugin.html).

However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the XML files to be generated unless I use the deprecated `@goal` tag in my JavaDoc comment above the Mojo.

Here is a snippet of my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- annotations used to describe the plugin metadata -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-descriptor</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-helpmojo</id>
                   <goals>
                        <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</project>
```

(You can find the full version [here](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/blob/main/pom.xml))

And here is an example of one of the Mojo's:

```java
/**
 * Run the configured recipes and apply the changes locally.
 * <p>
 * This variant of rewrite:run will fork the maven life cycle and can be run as a "stand-alone" goal. It will
 * execute the maven build up to the process-test-classes phase.
 */
@Mojo(name = "run", requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST, threadSafe = true,
        defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES)
@Execute(phase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES)
public class RewriteRunMojo extends AbstractRewriteRunMojo {
}
```

(You can find the code for the full project [here](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin))

When I run the `plugin:descriptor` goal, I get an error that says: `No mojo definitions were found for plugin: org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin.`

If I update my Mojo to have the `@goal` annotation in the JavaDoc such as in:

```java
/**
 * Run the configured recipes and apply the changes locally.
 * <p>
 * This variant of rewrite:run will fork the maven life cycle and can be run as a "stand-alone" goal. It will
 * execute the maven build up to the process-test-classes phase.
 *
 * @goal run
 */
@Mojo(name = "run", requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST, threadSafe = true,
        defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES)
@Execute(phase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES)
public class RewriteRunMojo extends AbstractRewriteRunMojo {
}
```

then I correctly get a `plugin-help.xml` file that looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Generated by maven-plugin-tools 3.9 (for help'mojo with additional elements)-->

<plugin>
  <name>rewrite-maven-plugin</name>
  <description>Eliminate technical debt. At build time.</description>
  <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <goalPrefix>rewrite</goalPrefix>
  <mojos>
    <mojo>
      <goal>run</goal>
      <description>Run the configured recipes and apply the changes locally. 
This variant of rewrite:run will fork the maven life cycle and can be run as a &quot;stand-alone&quot; goal. It will execute the maven build up to the process-test-classes phase.
</description>
      ....
    </mojo>
  </mojos>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, I get a warning that I'm using a deprecated extractor. However, I can't figure out how to generate an XML file with information about the goals *without* using this deprecated path.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? Would greatly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java-annotations` extractor discover annotation from compiled classes.

So first you need compile your project.

You need not execute direct goal `plugin:descriptor` it is bind in proper maven build phase.

simply try:

```
mvn process-classes
```

You also not need:

```
<execution>
 <id>default-descriptor</id>
 <phase>process-classes</phase>
</execution>
```

it is add by default for `maven-plugin` package